# Converting RDD to DataFrame scala - NoSuchMethodError

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to convert an RDD to a DataFrame in scala as follows

```
val posts = spark.textFile("~/allPosts/part-02064.xml.gz")

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.rdd._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(spark)
import sqlContext.implicits._

posts.map(identity).toDF()
```

When I do this I get the following error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$implicits$.stringRddToDataFrameHolder(Lorg/apache/spark/rdd/RDD;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameHolder;
```

I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Missing a jar, or a version mismatch?

Comment: I'm using spark 1.3 on scala 2.10 so I'm not sure about a version mismatch. It's weird because I've been working on this for a while and this is the first time it has come up.

Comment: Are you using a notebook ? e.g jupyter or toree ?

Comment: yeah, i'm using a jupyter notebook.

Comment: I've also noticed that with the notebook last week. I'm not sure if it's a bug.

Comment: Can you try using sqlContext.createDataFrame instead ?

Comment: It spits out an error complaining that sqlContext is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to define a schema to convert a RDD  to Dataframes either by Reflection method or via programmatically.

One very important point about Dataframes- Dataframe is a RDD with a schema. In your case define a case class and map the values of a file to that class. Hope it will help